# Why is a computation much slower within a Dask/Distributed worker?

Tags: python, distributed, dask

I have a computation which runs much slower within a Dask/Distributed worker compared to running it locally. I can reproduce it without any I/O going on, so I can rule out that it has to do with transferring data. The following code is a minimal reproducing example:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster


def gen_data(N=5000000):
    """ Dummy data generator """
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(N))
    for c in range(10):
        df[str(c)] = np.random.uniform(size=N)
    df["id"] = np.random.choice(range(100), size=len(df))
    return df


def do_something_on_df(df):
    """ Dummy computation that contains inplace mutations """
    for c in range(df.shape[1]):
        df[str(c)] = np.random.uniform(size=df.shape[0])
    return 42


def run_test():
    """ Test computation """
    df = gen_data()
    for key, group_df in df.groupby("id"):
        do_something_on_df(group_df)


class TimedContext(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        self.t1 = time.time()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.t2 = time.time()
        print(self.t2 - self.t1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = Client("tcp://10.0.2.15:8786")

    with TimedContext():
        run_test()

    with TimedContext():
        client.submit(run_test).result()
```

Running the test computation locally takes ~10 seconds, but it takes ~30 seconds from within Dask/Distributed. I also noticed that the Dask/Distributed workers output a lot of log messages like

```
distributed.core - WARNING - Event loop was unresponsive for 1.03s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.
distributed.core - WARNING - Event loop was unresponsive for 1.25s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.
distributed.core - WARNING - Event loop was unresponsive for 1.91s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.
distributed.core - WARNING - Event loop was unresponsive for 1.99s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.
distributed.core - WARNING - Event loop was unresponsive for 1.50s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.
distributed.core - WARNING - Event loop was unresponsive for 1.90s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.
distributed.core - WARNING - Event loop was unresponsive for 2.23s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.
...
```

which are surprising, because it's not clear what is holding the GIL in this example.

Why is there such a big performance difference? And what can I do to get the same performance?

*Disclaimer: Self answering for documentation purposes...*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This behavior is a result of a very surprising behavior of Pandas. By default, Pandas `__setitem__` handlers perform checks to detect chained assignments, leading to the famous `SettingWithCopyWarning`. When dealing with a copy, these checks issue a call to `gc.collect` [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/b70b05c620f929e8a69e022bd0a9850fa040c88e/pandas/core/generic.py#L2335). Thus, code that uses `__setitem__` excessively will result in excessive `gc.collect` calls. This can have a significant impact on performance in general, but the problem is much worse within a Dask/Distributed worker, because the garbage collection has to deal with much more Python data structures compared to running stand-alone. Most likely the hidden garbage collection calls are also the source of the GIL-holding warnings.

Therefore, the solution is to avoid these excessive `gc.collect` calls. There are two ways:

- Avoiding to use `__setitem__` on copies: Arguably the best solution, but it requires some understanding of where copies are produced. In the above example this could be achieved by changing the function call to `do_something_on_df(group_df.copy())`.
- Disabling chained assignment checks: Simply placing `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None` at the beginning of the computation also disables the `gc.collect` calls.

In both cases the test computation runs much faster than before with ~3.5 seconds both locally and under Dask/Distributed. This also gets rid of the GIL-holding warnings.

Note: I have filed an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18743) for this on GitHub.